# Differentiating between multiple HTML tables created in the same foreach loop

Tags: jquery, html

I have a loop in HTML that can create multiple tables based on an unique number (creates a table for unique number, gets the next unique number, creates next table, etc...).  The table header has a drop down that should filter the results in a particular table.  When I only have one table, the filter works fine (.hide/.show  on the rows needing filtered). When there are multiple tables, (and this is where I'm a bit confused and need some guidance) it appears to be looking at the wrong table for the filtered info and all table data for all tables is removed.

So for example only, I have two tables that have been created in the same  tag for "Routing Numbers" ('RN'1 table and 'RN' 2 table) and each table consists of banks and bank info within that unique routing number.  (ex:  'RN' = 1, 'Banks' drop down = Akron, Cincinnati, Cleveland - So if I choose Cincinnati, I should see only Cincinnati Bank info - the other rows should be hidden), but it looks as if everything has been filtered to '.hide'.

Is there a way to tell the difference between multiple tables that have been created with the same table ID, class in a for loop??

Here is my "Hide/Show" code:

```
function hideRIDRows() {
    $('#table2ID tbody tr').show();
    var sel_rid = $('select[name="RID"] option:selected').text();

    if (sel_rid == '-- Routing ID List --') {
    return;
    }

    $('#table2ID tbody tr').each(function () {
         var col_rid = $(this).find('td').eq(2).text();
         if (col_rid !== sel_rid) {
             $(this).hide();
         }
    });
}
```

EDIT:  I'm including the table logic (basic info only - because of bank secrets and all ;) )

```
<table style="margin-bottom:20px" class="table2" id="table2ID">
@{
    bool col = false;
    routingNo= "";
    List<string> RoutingNos = new List<string>();

     int count = 0;
    <thead>
             @foreach (var item in Model.Where(t => t.RoutingID == Convert.ToInt32(p)))
            {
                if (routingNo!= item.RoutingID.ToString())
                {
                    count = Model.Where(t => t.RoutingID== Convert.ToInt32(p)).Count() + 1;
                    routingNo= item.RoutingID.ToString();
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan=@count>Routing ID: @routingNo</th>
                    </tr>
                }
            <tr>
                <th colspan=@count>

                    <select name="RID" id ="RouteID" style="width:150px" class="routing">
                        <option style="text-align:center" value="">-- Routing ID List --</option>
                        @foreach (string city in OrderedCityList)
                        {
                            <option id="selection">@city</option>
                        }
                  </select>
                </th>
            </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody class="tbody2" id="tbody2ID">
@foreach (var city in OrderedCityList)
            {
            <tr>

              ***BANK INFO
                }

  </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
    }
}
</table>
```

Comment: The easiest way is to give each table a separate ID, or at the very least it's own data attribute, like `data-table-id="123"` then you can access it like `$('table[data-table-id="' + 123 + '"]')`

Comment: @Tallboy how would i go about that if all tables displayed are created in the same for loop?  ie.. lets say there are 4 tables now,  would i do something like this:  Foreach(var Routing in RoutingList){id = counter + 1}

Comment: @Taplar .. This is because it is the same table, just displayed multiple times.  If that helps - it's stumped me for a while also

Answer (score 2):

Instead of repeating ids, use a class instead.  Ids are expected to be unique and repeating them is invalid markup.  So instead when you create your tables do something like.

```
<table class="myTable">
```

Then lets say you have a button in the table to show/hide it.

```
<input type="button" class="hideMe" value="Hide Me">
```

Then when you bind you can base your logic off of the button clicked to get the table it belongs to.

```
$('.hideMe').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('.myTable').hide();
});
```

This is simple logic, but hopefully it conveys the concept.

For reference: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: this works excellent for one table, but if i were to wrap your <table class="mytable"> in a for loop, (and i can have up to 20 different numbers on my list) I'm "displaying "myTable" up to 20x.

Comment: It would still work, since it does the lookups contextually.  closest() finds the '.myTable' that it is a child of, not any of the others.

Comment: Ok that makes sense.  But if thats the case why does the filter only work when one table is displayed vs when multi displayed?  And i'm a newbie so please excuse my question if it sounds stupid.  This has really stumped me for about 3 days (probably longer if honest)

Comment: I would have to see how you are implementing my suggestion to see where the issue is.  Make sure any lookup you perform is acting like the click handler is up above.  It will need to find elements in the table in the same manner.  Not with a global lookup or with an id(since you are repeating fields).

Comment: Ok .. I will try that out and see what happens.  In the meantime i'll see if i can recreate the example in fiddle.  Thanks for your help!!

Comment: No worries.  So long as you find the help you need, ^_^